# Averaging columns in a text file with row and column headers

Tags: python, parsing

I'm new to the group, and to python. I have a very specific type of input file that I'm working with. It is a text file with one header row of text. In addition there is a column of text too which makes things more annoying. What I want to do is read in this file, and then perform operations on the columns of numbers (like average, stdev, etc)...but reading in the file and parsing out the text column is giving me trouble.

I've played with many different approaches and got it close, but figured I'd reach out to the group here. If this were matlab I'd have had it down hours ago. As of now if I used fixed width to define my columns, I think it will work, but I thought there is likely a more efficient way to read in the lines and ignore strings properly.

Here is the file format. As you can see, row one is header...so can be ignored.
column 1 contains text.

[postraw.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uG4NY.png)

....I think I figured it out. My code is probably very crude, but it works for now:

```
CTlist = []
CLlist = []
CDlist = []
CMZlist = []
LDelist = []
loopout = {'a1':CTlist, 'a2':CLlist, 'a3':CDlist, 'a4':CMZlist, 'a5':LDelist}

#Specifcy number of headerlines
headerlines = 1

#set initial index to 0
i = 0

#begin loop to process input file, avoiding any header lines
with open('post.out', 'r') as file:
    for row in file:
    if i > (headerlines - 1):
     rowvars = row.split()
     for i in range(2,len(rowvars)):
        #print(rowvars[i]) #JUST A CHECK/DEBUG LINE
        loopout['a{0}'.format(i-1)].append(float(rowvars[i]))
    i = i+1
```

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: I think I figured it out. Took a lot of digging around and like I said, I'm still very new at python. My code is likely very crude...but it works:

Answer (score 0):

```
CTlist = []
CLlist = []
CDlist = []
CMZlist = []
LDelist = []
loopout = {'a1':CTlist, 'a2':CLlist, 'a3':CDlist, 'a4':CMZlist, 'a5':LDelist}

#Specifcy number of headerlines
headerlines = 1

#set initial index to 0
i = 0

#begin loop to process input file, avoiding any header lines
with open('post.out', 'r') as file:
for row in file:
if i > (headerlines - 1):
 rowvars = row.split()
 for i in range(2,len(rowvars)):
    #print(rowvars[i]) #JUST A CHECK/DEBUG LINE
    loopout['a{0}'.format(i-1)].append(float(rowvars[i]))
i = i+1
```